# Variance: Why is $\lim_{N\to\infty}[\frac{1}{N}\sum(x_i-\mu)^2]$ equal to $\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{1}{N}\sum x_i^2)-\mu^2$?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Can anyone help me explain why the second equal sign is true for the variance?

$$\sigma^{2} \equiv \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{1}{N} \sum\left(x_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}\right]=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum x_{i}^{2}\right)-\mu^{2}$$

$\mu \equiv \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum x_{i}\right)$ is the mean of the population. 
 And $\sum x_{i} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i}$ is the measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have \begin{align} &\lim_{N\to\infty}\big(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i - \mu)^2\big) = \lim_{N\to\infty}\big( \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i^2-2\mu x_i + \mu^2)\big)=\\&=\lim_{N\to\infty} \big(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\big) - 2\mu \lim_{N\to\infty}\big(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\big) + \mu^2 \lim_{N\to\infty}\big(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N 1\big) = \\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\big(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\big) - 2\mu\cdot \mu + \mu^2\cdot 1 = \\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\big(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\big) -\mu^2 \end{align}

Comment: I think in this question $\mu$ is only the limit of the average, not the actual average for any particular value of $N.$

Comment: @DavidK You're right, I've corrected the answer.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing. But I see that there are som basic rules with limits, that I was unaware of. Why is it, that we can ignore the limit sign and say: $\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i}=N \mu$

Comment: @mhj You actually can't, I've corrected the answer. The equality holds only under the limit.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum\left(x_{i}-\mu\right)^{2} - \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum x_{i}^{2}-\mu^{2}\right)= 2\mu^2 -2 \mu \frac{1}{N} \sum x_i = 2\mu\left(\mu - \frac{1}{N} \sum x_i\right)$$

so your second equality is a consequence of $\lim\limits_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum x_{i}=\mu$, from the Law of Large Numbers